# Contentful API Throwing Strange Errors

Tags: javascript, contentful

I am using the contentful API through the package found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/contentful and for some reason I am getting a type error "TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken". Now I am calling the client with the access token directly for testing:

```
client = contentful.createClient({
    space: 'SPACE ID',
    accessToken: 'ACCESS TOKEN'
});
```

I am not sure how or why I am still getting this error. Has anyone else run into this? I am running this on an express server which I haven't worked with in years so maybe there is a lack on knowlege there but this is an extreamly simple one that just hydrates a react app for SSR.

Cheers,

Comment: Hello Josh, without source code it's hard to tell what's going on. Are you sure you're handing over the correct space id and contentful delivery access token?

Comment: I am sure I am handing over both correctly. As for source code the issue is localized to that one function. I see the error and trace it there even though I am for sure passing a accessToken. I have tested logs before and after and I get the same issue.

Comment: If you provide some encapsulated example code I'm happy to have a look. Unfortunately, without code it's hard to help. :/